# How to Post Application/Json Type using Retrofit and RxJava Android

Tags: java, android, retrofit, rx-java2

I'm stuck with posting the just the title and location which is Array of lat and long, I need to check this. I know this is not the enough context. I'll edit further please help me understanding this step by step.

```
JsonObject jsonObject = new JsonObject();
jsonObject.addProperty("title","Dombivli");
JsonArray locationArray = new JsonArray();
locationArray.add(19.2093305);
locationArray.add(73.0645624);
jsonObject.add("location", locationArray);

subscription.add(createPointsOfViewModel.postAdd(jsonObject).subscribe(new Observer<PostPojo>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        Toast.makeText(CreatePointsOfInterestActivity.this, "Complete", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
```

The Service method:

```
public interface CreatePointsOfInterestService {
    @Headers({
            "Accept: application/json",
            "Content-Type: application/json"
    })
    @POST("http://dev.citrans.net:8888/skymeet/swagger-ui.html#!/poi-controller/saveProductUsingPOST")
        rx.Observable<PostPojo> postAdd(@Body JsonObject body);
    }
```

The JSON I want to add in:

```
{
  "createdAt": "2018-08-09T05:49:42.958Z",
  "createdBy": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "id": "string",
  "imageUrl": "string",
  "location": [
    0
  ],
  "poiId": "string",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "title": "string",
  "updatedAt": "2018-08-09T05:49:42.958Z",
  "updatedBy": "string",
  "version": 0
}
```

Comment: post the json you will get from response ?

Comment: No from the App to the API

Comment: post the json you will send to request ?

Comment: just add a content type header

Comment: I did that too @VladyslavMatviienko

Comment: @sushildlh you need the Json example?

Comment: yes @Mr.Imposter please upload your request json on question

Comment: {
  "createdAt": "2018-08-09T05:49:42.958Z",
  "createdBy": "string",
  "description": "string",
  "id": "string",
  "imageUrl": "string",
  "location": [
    0
  ],
  "poiId": "string",
  "status": "ACTIVE",
  "title": "string",
  "updatedAt": "2018-08-09T05:49:42.958Z",
  "updatedBy": "string",
  "version": 0
}

Answer (score 0):

Your API URL is wrong. Seems you are passing the [page URL](http://dev.citrans.net:8888/skymeet/swagger-ui.html#!/poi-controller/saveProductUsingPOST) instead of API URL.
Update your URL as follow:

```
@POST("http://dev.citrans.net:8888/skymeet/poi/add")
```

instead of

```
@POST("http://dev.citrans.net:8888/skymeet/swagger-ui.html#!/poi-controller/saveProductUsingPOST")
```

Also, noted that in response it is giving 200 status code in Postman but there may be some problem in response from the server. So by replacing above API URL, your API will be called successfully but you have to check response with backend developer.

Comment: What error are you getting? Can you show me your error log of response?

Answer (score 0):

Send the full URL as @Url parameter in the interface,

```
@POST
rx.Observable<PostPojo> postAdd(@Url String url, @Body JsonObject body);
```